# Is there a way in Node.js to convert WCF-binary data to full text XML representation?

Tags: xml, node.js, wcf, binary, npm

Is there a way in Node.js (some npm package, for example) to convert binary encoded WCF data (response from some SOAP server) to its full text XML representation?

[For example, having this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTfsf.png)

[I want to receive this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IvJr.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... After searching hard I've found no ready solution, so decided to write my own.
I had some free time and have wrote the npm package 'wcf2xml'.
If You also look for something like this, please feel free to use my solution.

NPM package page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wcf2xml

GitHub page: https://github.com/tumick/wcf2xml

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that there will be one... Binary format as it is intended for intranet scenarios using NetTcpBinding and not designed for inter-op. You can add additional WS* endpoint to your original service or you can create WCF service that "translates" from binary to SOAP and call it.